# How can I find out the running kernel version without running uname or proc/version?

Tags: linux, kernel

How can I find out the running kernel version without running "uname -a" or "cat /proc/version"
given that there can be multiple vmlinuz files in /boot.

I have a corrupted disk and I attached it to another linux and mounted it. I am trying to understand what linux kernel was running on this corrupted disk, that's why I am trying to find an alternative way to find out the running kernel version

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `cat /proc/version`? This sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I have a corrupted disk and I attached it to another linux and mounted it. I am trying to understand what linux kernel was running on this corrupted disk. So I can't technically use uname or /proc/version

Comment: @WagdeZabit, for offline detection, check logs or bootloader (grub) configuration files, or directories in /lib/modules. On every boot there is usually some log in `/var/log` which records text from kernel's dmesg buffer (check /var/log/messages, /var/log/dmesg).

Answer (score 0):

may be `dmesg | grep Linux` could work

dmesg obtains kernel data by reading the kernel ring buffer and since there may be many information , you could just use grep command to find the Linux kernel 
Similarly to find any other information you  could use grep with other keyword

Comment: it could work, but in some cases the message could have been deleted due to cyclic dmesg

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @double-beep edited the answer, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I edited the question to include an explanation, why I can't use uname or proc/version